# QLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax - LARAVEL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

Plz, can you help me, i get this error

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where is_read = 0 ) as unread from `messages` left join `users` on `users`.`id`' at line 1 (SQL: select `users`.`id`, `users`.`name`, `users`.`avatar`, `users`.`email`, `users`.`is_owner`, `messages`.`from`, `messages`.`created_at`, (SELECT count(messages.is_read) where is_read = 0 ) as unread from `messages` left join `users` on `users`.`id` = `messages`.`from` where `messages`.`to` = 175 and `users`.`id` != 175 group by `users`.`id` order by `messages`.`created_at` desc)

and this is my query inside laravel

```
$my_id = Auth::user()->id;

 
   $users = DB::table('messages')->leftJoin('users' , 'users.id' , '=' , 'messages.from')
  
   ->select('users.id' , 'users.name' , 'users.avatar' , 'users.email', 'users.is_owner' , 'messages.from' , 'messages.created_at' , 
        DB::raw("(SELECT count(messages.is_read)  where is_read = 0  ) as unread"))
   ->where('messages.to' , $my_id)
   ->where('users.id' , '!=' , $my_id)
   ->groupBy('users.id' )
   ->orderBy('messages.created_at', 'desc')
   ->get();
```

And this is only problem at my live server, at my localhost (xampp) it works fine, plz can you help me, because i can't see problem.

P.S.
When i remove this part `DB::raw("(SELECT count(messages.is_read)  where is_read = 0  ) as unread"))`
it works fine, where is mistake here?

Comment: You have to ad from tablename, so select count() from tablename where is_read=0

Comment: thx man, this is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing the table

It should be

```
SELECT COUNT(is_read) FROM messages WHERE is_read=0;
```

Comment: thx, a lot, i am new in this, yes that is solution